# Genymotion performance problems with Android 4.4.4, 5.0.0 and 5.1.0

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator, genymotion

I'm using [this page](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/3d-transforms/) to test CSS 3D transforms in Android on Genymotion and I came along the following problem. When I load that page in the preinstalled browser of Android 4.1.1 and 4.2.2 the animations on that page are running extremly smooth at high FPS.

But when I run that page on Genymotion Android 4.4.4, 5.0.0 or 5.1.0 the animations have a really poor performance. It is going so slow that I can count the FPS rate with naked eye. Also booting the emulator takes about 5x the time compared to 4.1.1 and 4.2.2. Is it possible that hardware acceleration isn't working with those images?
I tried to tweak the VMs in virtual box and applied the same settings as to the 4.1.1 and 4.2.2 virtual machines but it didn't speed it up. 3D Hardware acceleration is enabled in VBox for all of those virtual machines as you can see in the screenshots.

That problem occurred on two different Machines. AMD - Win7 and Intel Core2 Quad (Q9550) 8GB RAM - Vista. Both have powerful 3D graphic cards and hardware virtualization enabled in BIOS setup.

Any suggestions? Or do you experience the same behavior with your Genymotion setup?

VBox version is 4.3.28 r 100309. Genymotion version is 2.4.0 Revision 20150225-8d7d43d.

[image: Genymotion Android 4.4.4 VBox settings]
[image: Genymotion Android 4.1.1 VBox settings]

Comment: Finding the same thing on Macbook Pro 13" and Macbook Air 13". Android 4.2.2 VMs are as snappy as you would expect, but 4.4 and 5.0 are very sluggish.

Comment: In the meanwhile Genymotion and VirtualBox released new versions, so I updated to Genymotion 2.5.0 and VirtualBox 5.0.0 but still the same. Of course the Genymotion support does not answer.

Comment: Having the same problem. 4.3 is fast but 4.4 and higher much slower.

Comment: It's getting worst with 5.0+ builds